# Select regression coefs by name

Tags: r

After running a regression, how can I select the variable name and corresponding parameter estimate?

For example, after running the following regression, I obtain:

```
set.seed(1)
n=1000
x=rnorm(n,0,1)
y=.6*x+rnorm(n,0,sqrt(1-.6)^2)
(reg1=summary(lm(y~x)))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.2994 -0.2688 -0.0055  0.3022  1.4577 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -0.006475   0.013162  -0.492    0.623    
x            0.602573   0.012723  47.359   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.4162 on 998 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6921,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6918 
F-statistic:  2243 on 1 and 998 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

I would like to be able to select the coefficient by the variable names (e.g., `(Intercept)  -0.006475`)

I have tried the following but nothing works...

```
attr(reg1$coefficients,"terms")
names(reg1$coefficients)
```

*Note:* This works `reg1$coefficients[1,1]` but I want to be able to call it by the name rather than row / column.

Comment: you can try `coefficients(reg1)["(Intercept)", 1]` and the same for `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your code doesn't run the way you have it.  I changed it a bit:

```
set.seed(1)
n=1000
x=rnorm(n,0,1)
y=.6*x+rnorm(n,0,sqrt(1-.6)^2)
model = lm(y~x)
```

Now, I can call `coef(model)["x"]` or `coef(model)["(Intercept)"]` and get the values.

```
> coef(model)["x"]
       x 
0.602573 
> coef(model)["(Intercept)"]
 (Intercept) 
-0.006474794
```

Answer (score 2):

The package broom tidies a lot of regression models very nicely.

```
require(broom)
set.seed(1)
n=1000
x=rnorm(n,0,1)
y=.6*x+rnorm(n,0,sqrt(1-.6)^2)
model = lm(y~x)
tt <- tidy(model, conf.int=TRUE)

subset(tt,term=="x")
##   term estimate  std.error statistic       p.value  conf.low conf.high
## 2    x 0.602573 0.01272349  47.35908 1.687125e-257 0.5776051 0.6275409

with(tt,tt[term=="(Intercept)","estimate"])
## [1] -0.006474794
```